# How to create an Angular Material Dialog factory?

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material, factory

I have a few dialogs in one component. They all look pretty much the same so I would like to make a function that would call different dialogs with different messages. This is what I have already come up with:
current dialog call:

```ts
 deActivate(user: UsersList) {
     const dialog = this.dialog.open(DeactivateUserDialogComponent, {
         height: '20%',
         width: '50%',
         data: {
             dialogMessage: user
         }
     });
     dialog.componentInstance.onChange.subscribe(() => this.getUsers());
 }
```

So my idea is to make a universal Dialog:

```ts
openDialog(dialogName, message) {
     const dialog = this.dialog.open(dialogName, {
         data: {
             dialogMessage: message
         }
     });
     dialog.componentInstance.onChange.subscribe(() => {
         this.getUsers(), dialog.close();
     });
 }
```

And call the method:

```ts
openDialog(userDeleted: UsersList) {
    this.openDialog(DeactivateUserDialogComponent, user);
}
```

but the problem is with the `dialog.componentInstance
"it cannot exist on type {}"`.
I need the `componentInstance` to make an update in the parent component (this is the only way it works without refresh). So what can I do make the factory and not worry about the refresh?

Comment: Wait... Doesn't the method in the last code block just call itself? It'll probably cause an infinite loop!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it wasn't so hard :) 
Actually, I don't need the componentInstance. Instead I need to close the dialog in the dialog component and afterClose in parent component. Works just fine